# How to handle folder of git submodule which is marked as "untracked" in the host repo?

Tags: git, version-control, integration-testing, git-submodules

I've got a code base in which I want to add another repo as a submodule to do some integration testing. So following a tutorial I ran

```
git submodule add -b master git@gitlab.com:kramer65/whisky.git
```

After that, a `git status` gives me this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitmodules
    whisky/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

As you can see the `.gitmodules` file is new, but the `whisky/` folder also appears as untracked. After this I committed the `.gitmodules` file, but the `whisky/` folder still appears as untracked.

How should I handle this? Do I need to add the `whisky/` folder also to the "host repo"? Or do I need to add it to `.gitignore`? Or is there another way to handle this?

Comment: Add it with `git add whisky`.

Answer (score 1):

Just rerun `git submodule add <URL>`.

Git will see *whisky/* as a submodule and won't track its files.

You can check it through `git diff --cached whisky/` (git will only see it as a particular commit)

After all, just commit it.

[See more here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)